# Sending data from Android app to MySQL database

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am a newbie attempting to send data from an Android app to a MySQL database set up on a localhost server via xampp. This method is supposed to put a name, username, password, phone number, and age into an arraylist of type NameValuePair.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            ArrayList<NameValuePair> dataToSend = new ArrayList<>();
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", user.name));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("age", user.age + ""));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", user.username));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", user.password));
            dataToSend.add(new BasicNameValuePair("phoneNumber", user.phoneNumber));

        HttpParams httpRequestParams = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(httpRequestParams, CONNECTION_TIMEOUT);

        HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(httpRequestParams);

        HttpPost post = new HttpPost("localhost/Register.php");

        try{
            post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(dataToSend));
            client.execute(post);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

When I run the application, I receive the following exception:

```
Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=localhost/Register.php
```

My research leads me to believe that there's a problem with the url string, but I don't know specifically what the issue is.

Thanks in advance.

(P.S. I am also aware of the awful security implications of storing a password in plain text on a database. Just trying to learn how to interact between apps and databases. Thx)

Comment: Try to set 10.0.2.2 this IP instead of localhost

Comment: @SarvagnaMehta what exactly does this do?

Comment: It connects you to localhost, because in some emulators localhost is directly not working.

Comment: use url like this `"http://SYSTEM_IP_ADDRESS/Register.php"`

Comment: @bharat is SYSTEM_IP_ADDRESS the same as the localhost address?

Comment: you are missing `http://`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was simply that I was using the wrong ip address. For some reason or another, localhost does not work. I figured out my system's ipv4 address (not 10.0.2.2) and used that and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code to post data if the localhost replacement doesn't work for you.

```
   HttpParams params = new DefaultHttpParams(); // setup whatever params you what
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost("someurl");
    post.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity()); // with list of key-value pairs
    client.execute(post, new ResponseHandler(){}); // implement ResponseHandler to handle response correctly.
```